# How to attach carrier wave version inline in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, actionmailer

I have a tidbit model that has a carrierwave uploader.  Im working on attaching an inline image in an email.  If I do this:

```
  @filename = @tidbit.image.instance_variable_get('@file').filename
  attachments.inline[@filename] = @tidbit.image.read
```

I get an inline image in my email.  However, it is the full size original version.

How would I inline attach a specific version (i.e..  :thumb) of the image?

If I do:

```
  attachments.inline[@filename] = @tidbit.image(:thumb).read
```

I get an argument error 1 for 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late reply, but it might help googlers and I had to do something similar. The following worked:

These are the versions present on my uploader class

```
version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [122, 70]
end
version :medium do
  process :resize_to_fill => [470, 470]
end
```

So to get the image in a certain version I just need to do, for example:

```
specific_version = uploader.image.medium.read
```

Where **medium** is the version I want.

In the original question's case you need to do:

```
attachments.inline[@filename] = @tidbit.image.thumb.read
```